# Regular expressions help, matching digits

Tags: regex, tcl

I can't seem to extract the 40x12 for some reason in TCL. Any help with this?

```
set l "zzzzzmbl01a40x12bbbbbbb"
set prefix "zzzzz"
if {[regexp "^${prefix}(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(\d+x\d+).+$" $l match var1 var2 var3]} {
puts $var1
puts $var2
puts $var3
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you should brace the regexp to avoid escaping certain characters (such as backslash and square brackets), but since you are using a variable within the regexp, you have to use quotes. This also means that you will have to escape those characters otherwise you wouldn't have to escape if you used braces instead. When escaping these, we get:

```
regexp "^${prefix}(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(\\d+x\\d+).+$" $l match var1 var2 var3
```

Now that this is taken care of, there is one last issue with the expression itself:

```
regexp "^${prefix}(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(\\d+x\\d+).+$" $l match var1 var2 var3
                                       ^^
```

These will match `a4` in your original string because the `.+` is greedy. Overall I would use lazy quantifiers and/or use slightly more precise regexp (but since I don't know the structure of your string to be matched, this might not work for all your cases):

Lazy quantifiers (all the quantifiers will be lazy after the first one, it's just better be explicit by making all the other quantifiers lazy):

```
regexp "^${prefix}(.+?)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+?(\\d+?x\\d+?)\\D.+?$" $l match var1 var2 var3
```

More precise:

```
regexp -nocase "^${prefix}([a-z]*)(l01|l02|l03|l04)[a-z]*(\\d+x\\d+).+?$" $l match var1 var2 var3
```

There is one more thing that could be improved, `(l01|l02|l03|l04)` can technically be substituted by `(l0[1-4])`, but only if `(l01|l02|l03|l04)` are the only possibilities from your string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to double the backslashes on the `\d`s:

```
regexp "^${prefix}(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(\\d+x\\d+).+$" $l ...
```

Whenever you pass arguments that aren't enclosed in braces, they are evaluated before being passed to the command. In this case you need to do this, since you want to substitute the value of a variable inside the pattern argument. Evaluated arguments can be tricky, but a simple trick lets us inspect them:

```
% regexp "^${prefix}(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(\d+x\d+).+$" $l
0
% list regexp "^${prefix}(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(\d+x\d+).+$" $l
regexp {^zzzzz(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(d+xd+).+$} zzzzzmbl01a40x12bbbbbbb
```

When the `list` command is invoked, all its arguments are evaluated, and then they are returned in their evaluated form. Now it's easy to see that evaluation stripped off the backspaces from the `\d`s.

To avoid unwanted evaluation, one can use a limited `subst`:

```
% subst -nocommands -nobackslashes {^${prefix}(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(\d+x\d+).+$}
^zzzzz(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(\d+x\d+).+$
```

(You can abbreviate the options: `-noc`, `-nob`.)

Another way to get the same result is to use `format`:

```
format {^%s(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(\d+x\d+).+$} $prefix
```

In Tcl 8.6.2 or later, you can do this:

```
string cat ^ $prefix {(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(\d+x\d+).+$}
```

In earlier versions you can do it this way (creates the variable `pat`):

```
append pat ^ $prefix {(.+)(l01|l02|l03|l04).+(\d+x\d+).+$}
```

Documentation:
[append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm),
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[subst](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)